# Unexpected generation of plasma far from HV rod electrode. Why is plasma being generated near the encircled part wherein there shouldn't be?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, plasma-physics, inert-gases

[image]we have built a kHz jet plasma reactor and we are generating plasma at the inlet side every time we increase input voltage to more than 3 kV. Working gas used was argon at 1 slm entering at the side. I attached the reactor we made here and the bottom part of the running reactor. You can see the issue at hand. [image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why is plasma being generated in that encircled part of the reactor system?

Comment: Are you sure plasma is being generated there and not propagating to that location?

Comment: I think you are correct propagating is the correct term. at less than 3kV there is no plasma in that location but plasma is generated near the grounded area. at more than 3kV though, plasma is seen propagating at the side inlet. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Isolate the argon inlet and add a potential relative to ground to prevent argon from flowing back in (i.e., positive potential).  You will attract electrons but if your inflow is high enough this can act to help ionize the inflowing argon, possibly.  Haven't thought about this much so think it through and possibly but someone like @JonCuster who knows a lot more about lab plasma devices.